# 555 HTTP Protocol when trying to scrape with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website using Scrapy. It gets access to robots.txt file with "status code 200"

But I get this in the terminal for sending a request:

```
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (555) <POST https://www.<the_link>.ca/<part_of_link>/UpdateQuery> (referer: None)
b'{"d":{"Message":"SESSION_TIMEOUT","Result":null,"Succeeded":false}}'
```

I have tried looking up on internet about 555. However, I could not find much explanation on it.

Got some information from https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/new-http-status-code-555" but nothing very clear.

I have tried it on Postman. The first time I send request I get 555 error and the second time I send request I get status code 200.

But, how do I tackle this on script in Scrapy?

I would be glad if someone can help me to get around this.

Thank you.

Comment: 5xx means you have supplied data to a server and the server could not handle it. 555 is an unofficial status code, used primarily be lambdas. You should try and post to the URL using Postman

Comment: Yes, I did try using Postman. Got the same 555 error for the first time request that was send. How do I fix it on Scrapy though?

Comment: could you please provide a link to the website from which do you want to collect info

Comment: If a third party system is throwing errors with out an error message, then it's hard to fix it. What I would recommend is finding an example where the POST request works and examine the HTTP Headers. I would usually start with Postman as it's a far easier tool to play around with (and then move the headers to Scrapy). It may be a simple as passing in the referer. Are you able to send a link to the URL?

Comment: Sure, I am actually trying to send a POST request to "https://www.centris.ca/property/UpdateQuery". And, I am gonna try it out on Postman. However, on Postman, when I send request for first time I get 555 error. Then when I press "Send" again I get status code 200. So, its like the first time I send a request, it doesn't work. The second time I do it, then it starts working.

Comment: I fixed it. There was a request sent before the request to update query. It was to unlock updating query. I missed that and so did the instructor of the course that I am following. Anyways, I guess it's the error I get before unlocking the process to update request.

Comment: @SadmanIshrak Could you explain how did you solve the problem. I tried to send the same request before the yield but I still get the same error.